# How can I do the RSA/ECB/PKCS1 Padding mode in Linux?

Tags: linux, encryption, openssl, rsa, padding

I am programming with Linux to encrypt a `.txt` file. I should encrypt a s2 chaine  with a given `PKI encryption key` using `RSA` in
`RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding` mode.

I have excecuted the following commands:

```
openssl rsautl -encrypt -pkcs -inkey Key.pem -pubin -in s2.txt -out rsa_4096.bin

openssl -encrypt -e -base64 -in rsa_4096.bin -out s2encrypted.txt
```

There is a problem with the padding mode.

Comment: "There is a problem with the padding mode."  What exactly is the problem? Currently we're a little short of crystal balls...

Comment: Normally the other part will decode my text. But he faced a problem when doing that with a java prog ==> BadPaddingException()

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right keys? Key mismatch will also manifest as BadPaddingException. Without knowing how the keys are handled on the java side it's difficult to tell if your commands are correct.

Comment: I have the private key in this form "MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8QPIWj......" I just create my .pem file by adding ------Begin key encryption ---- and -----end key encryption--- then change the extension from .txt to .pem and use it ..

Comment: You know that you do encryption with the public key and signing with the private key? So if you use the private key for encryption there's no wonder that the guy in the other side can't decrypt your message. By the way: you don't need -pkcs as PKCS1 is the default.

Comment: I meant public key .. I have the publilc key in that form and the exponent as well as the modulus.  Maybe the problem in the conversion of this string to .pem file . How should I do it?